# new Pandas Dataframe column calculated from other column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I create a new column in a dataframe that consists of the MEAN of an indexed range of values in that row?

example:

```
     1    2    3  JUNK
0  0.0  0.0  0.0    A    
1  1.0  1.0 -1.0    B    
2  2.0  2.0  1.0    C
```

the `JUNK` column would be ignored when trying to determine the MEAN column

expected output:

```
     1    2    3  JUNK  MEAN
0  0.0  0.0  0.0    A    0.0
1  1.0  1.0 -1.0    B    0.33
2  2.0  2.0  1.0    C    1.66
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) for removing or [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for filter out unnecessary columns:

```
df['MEAN'] = df.drop('JUNK', axis=1).mean(axis=1)
```

---

```
df['MEAN'] = df.iloc[:, :-1].mean(axis=1)

print (df)
     1    2    3 JUNK      MEAN
0  0.0  0.0  0.0    A  0.000000
1  1.0  1.0 -1.0    B  0.333333
2  2.0  2.0  1.0    C  1.666667
```